# Evaluation for non-blank input but allowing for blank spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm validating for non-blank input, but I am allowing for spaces, so that typical English can be input.

I have this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test(value));
});
```

Which will accept strings that have no spaces, otherwise it will not accept them.

Ex: It will accept `Stack` or `Overflow` but not `Stack Overflow`

I want to check for "at least one alphanumeric character *somewhere*". How may I go about this?

Note: If I am going about this in a conceptually inefficient way, please correct me, surely there is a standardized way of validating like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*| [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/.test(value));
});
```

Must be this ;)

Edit: RegExp missing /

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to evaluate properly - it messes up my other jQuery code, indicative of an error somewhere. I don't know regexp so I can't see if there is an error or not.

Comment: My bad i forgot a / before regexp expression ! /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*| [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/